# Packages for Beginners

Tags: java, package

When a classfile that belongs to a package, 
then

```
package PackageName;
```

is included in the source code of that file.
So when jvm is invoked by writing

```
java PackageName.classfilename
```

it gets executed.

Is it that "package PackageName" guarantees the jvm that this classfile belongs to this very package?
Because if we omit the "package PackageName" statement, then jvm still finds out the class file but gives

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Classfilename 
wrongname PackageName/ClassfileName
```

It means jvm finds out the file but there is some reason for which it considers that this classfile has a wrong name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package declarations on your classes must match the folder structure that you have for your code.
Packages are used by the JVM for several "tasks", from the visibility of methods, to the resolution of situations where two classes could have the same name.
A NoClassDefFoundError actually means the JVM *cannot* find the class with the package you gave it. If you ommit the package definition on the class, and run the program like:
    java ClassFileName
The JVM will find the class, as long as you're running the java command from the folder where your class is.

Also... package names should be all lowercase and Class names should start with an Uppercase. :) Conventions are really helpful when someone else is reading your code!

Hope the comment helped.

Answer (score 1):

The class file needs to exist on the file system in the same hierarchy as is defined in the package name. If you remove the package name, I believe you must have the file in the root folder of your jar to work in the "unnamed" package. Likely you removed the package line from the source file but still left the class definition inside of the `PackageName` folder.

Comment: Sir, I included proper package name and compiled to create the classfile,took it inside the package folder. There it got executed properly. Then I removed the class file and jvm could not find it hence the "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Classfilename" occured. Then I compiled the source code that didn't have "package statement" and took it to the package folder. This time jvm came up with  "Exception in thread "main" wrongname PackageName/ClassfileName". Hence i thought that jvm finds out the file but considers it to be a wrong file. Thank You Sir

Comment: Trivia time! This is a requirement of javac and java executables, not the Java language or Virtual Machine. Technically, the Java specifications (section 7.2 of the JLS and section 2.7 of the VM spec) do not require the source tree to match the package structure - it's an implementation decision. An example of an alternative storage mechanism is oracle db - it stores your source code and byte code in the database directly.